# How to register VLC as a multimedia player in Ubuntu system?

Tags: vlc, gnome-control-center

In "Preferences - Preferred Applications" there is a choice of Totem and Rhythmbox (actually it was, before I've uninsulated both of them favouring DeadBeeF for audio, raw mplayer for video and VLC for occasions) and Custom. Can I add a player (VLC for example) to appear in that list, officially recognised as a player application (not just "Custom")?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All the applications that are listed in *Preferred Applications* are registered in
`/usr/share/gnome-control-center/default-apps`.

To add VLC to the list of media players,

1. Create a file called `vlc.xml` in `/usr/share/gnome-control-center/default-apps`:
   Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> and run the following command:

   ```
   gksu gedit /usr/share/gnome-control-center/default-apps/vlc.xml
   ```
2. Copy and paste the following in that file:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <!DOCTYPE default-apps SYSTEM "gnome-da-list.dtd">
   <default-apps>
     <media-players>
       <media-player>
         <name>VLC</name>
         <executable>vlc</executable>
         <command>vlc</command>
         <icon-name>vlc</icon-name>
         <run-in-terminal>false</run-in-terminal>
       </media-player>
     </media-players>
   </default-apps>
   ```

---

You should now see *VLC*  in the list of multimedia players:

[image]

Comment: nice :)! This will come in handy :D